# Is 3 minutes to join a 50 million table too much?

Tags: mysql, performance, join, query-performance

I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask, but I really need some opinion on whether or not my query is good or not.

Basically, I need to get a count of old and invalid entries per group, which is identified by a value of NULL or simply a month old. The selected data is going to be stored in a smaller table called "statistics". PHP is used for a cron script.

Now, the problem is I'm still a novice so I can't tell if the query is fast or slow. To finish the following query, it takes roughly 3 minutes, which according to my boss is slow and needs to be at least 50% faster, but I myself am not sure if anything can be done to speed it up. "cat_01" table has 50 mil row, the others have less then 2000.

I did add indexes to all used columns, which lowered the time from 6 to 3 minutes.

The query I'm using is as follows (I used pseudonyms for tables and columns, so don't mind the logic):

```sql
SELECT 
'cat_01' as category,
m.shop_id,
o.name,
count(m.shop_id) as total,
tr2.traffic,
IF(mm.bought IS NULL,0,mm.bought) as bought 
FROM cat_01 m 
JOIN shops o 
ON m.shop_id = o.id 
JOIN (
    select 
    mmm.shop_id,
    max(mmm.buy_date) as bought 
    FROM cat_01 mmm 
    GROUP BY mmm.shop_id
) mm
ON o.id = mm.shop_id 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT tr.shop_id, sum(tr.sales) AS traffic 
    FROM (
        SELECT
        mmmmm.shop_id,
        bs.sales,
        bs.order_id,
        bs.id
        FROM cat_01 mmmmm
        JOIN orders bs
        ON mmmmm.order = bs.order_id 
    ) tr group by tr.shop_id
) tr2
ON tr2.shop_id = mm.shop_id 
WHERE (m.buy_date IS NULL)
OR (m.buy_date <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
GROUP BY m.shop_id
```

- Create table "cat01":

```sql
CREATE TABLE `cat_01` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `shop_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `buy_date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `order` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `shop_id` (`shop_id`),
 KEY `buy_date` (`buy_date`),
 KEY `order` (`order`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

- Create table "shops":

```sql
CREATE TABLE `shops` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

- create table "orders":

```sql
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `sales` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `order_id` (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here is the explain (I don't have access to the live data from home, so I used dummy rows, but rest is the same)

[image: explain]

**EDIT**: added UNIX_TIMESTAMP() as an example

**EDIT2**: I ended up removing the subqueries from the SELECT and used them seperately, then using a PHP loop, I created the appropriate INSERT query by mixing the results together.

P.S. I can't seem to find a direct example of how sql code formatting on sctackechange looks, so I apologize if it ends up garbled, I'll try to fix it shortly.

I do have an EXPLAIN result but not sure how to format that, might end up posting an image later.

**If you need some particular info, feel free to ask, I myself am not sure what I should be looking at.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FROM ( SELECT ... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... )
```

does not optimize well.  Think of a better way to write the query.  If that fails, put one of the subqueries into a `TEMPORARY TABLE` and add an index to it.

Consider using the datatype `DATE`, not `INT`, for dates.

`OR` is a performance killer (because it prevents use of an index).  Consider other ways to deal with `IS NULL`.

**More**

If `order_id` is unique in `orders`, then get rid if `id` and user `order_id` as the `PRIMARY KEY`.  (Plus any changes needed to other tables?)  Lookup by PK is faster than lookup by secondary key.

If the information in some of these tables is "static" (written once, but not updated or deleted), then consider building and maintaining a "Summary table".

For doing this query 13 times for 13 categories, it *may* be faster to do it once, with a `GROUP BY category_id`.

Turning `OR` into `UNION` *may* speed things up, especially if it lets a better index be used.

Comment: The summary table sounds kinda what I was thinking, that might be what I need(actually found an article you wrote), but will see if the fixes help as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, add these indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE cat_01
ADD INDEX `ShopBuyDates` (`shop_id`,`buy_date`)

ALTER TABLE orders
ADD INDEX `OrderSales` (`order_id`,`sales`)
```

Then try this query, and report the results. Make sure to run it at least twice, and discard the first result's performance, to flush out the effects of populating the cache.

```
SELECT 
'cat_01' as category,
m.shop_id,
o.name,
count(m.shop_id) as total,
tr2.traffic,
IF(mm.bought IS NULL,0,mm.bought) as bought 
FROM cat_01 m 
JOIN shops o 
ON m.shop_id = o.id 
JOIN (
    select 
    mmm.shop_id,
    max(mmm.buy_date) as bought 
    FROM cat_01 mmm 
    GROUP BY mmm.shop_id
) mm
ON o.id = mm.shop_id 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT mmmmm.shop_id, sum(bs.sales) AS traffic 
    FROM cat_01 mmmmm
    JOIN orders bs
    ON mmmmm.order = bs.order_id 
    group by mmmmm.shop_id
) tr2
ON tr2.shop_id = mm.shop_id 
WHERE (m.buy_date IS NULL)
OR (m.buy_date = 0)
OR (m.buy_date < 1)
GROUP BY m.shop_id
```

After we see the improvement from this (a new EXPLAIN would be good too, from this query), we can iterate to see what else is slowing down your query.

Comment: Thanks, will try it tommorow to see what changes (expect results in roughly 12-14 hours). I don't have access to the database from home, so it will have to wait a bit.

Comment: Sounds good, I check stackexchange multiple times a day usually, so will come back to this when you leave a comment again.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the wait. I tried to apply these, but there was almost no improvement (2-3 seconds faster). I did however take out the subqueries into a PHP DB query which in the end, combined with your indexes and the tips from Rick below, did speed up the whole thing up. I can still put up the results if you want though.